# MySQL returning NPE getting an ID from a table (as a string)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
private UUID getClientID(String username) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username=" + username;
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(2));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The table:

> id username password create_date
>
> id = c235a95d-58e7-4454-90ea-58396a00a3c5 username = myUsername
>   password = [BLOB - 16 B] create_date = Fri Apr 28 09:34:49 BST 2017

So why would it return null? I think I am doing something wrong with the `ResultSet`.

Comment: It's returning null because your method is catching the error and then returning null.  Where is the NPE?  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: You need to **execute** your query before you can get a result set.

Answer (score 5):

String should be between two `'username'` and you already use `PreparedStatement` so instead use :

```
String query = "SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username= ?";
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
   return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(1));
}else{
   return null;//id not found
}
```

**Note**

1. Your query return just one field, so it is wrong to use `rs.getString(2)` there are no second field
2. You have to execute the statement, then use `rs.next()` to get results

Comment: Short and effective answer :) +1

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very hard trouble shooting MySQL myself when I am not following a tutorial and do not have a mentor.

Comment: @J.Doe you can use that link that i already share you can understand more good luck :)